# What do soldiers say when you give an order to them?

Tags: soldiers-heroes-of-world-war-ii

Unfortunately, I don't have enough English listening skill to parse all that they say. But I managed to parse a few speeches:

> - Let's show who's boss around here!
> - Charge!
> - Piece a cake!
> - It seems that Germans are having a lucky day.

Where or how can I find out the full detailed list of their speeches?

Comment: I don’t play it but might be able to help. What do you mean by “detailed list of their speeches”? Are speeches just spoken randomly? What is the difference between a detailed lift and one that’s not detailed?